# JDBC Connect String for Oracle OID Using OCI Driver

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle-call-interface, oid

I know how to connect to oracle using OID and the thin client jdbc driver:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://server:port/xyz,cn=abc,dc=def,dc=ghi
```

I cannot, though, connect using jdbc, oci and oid. Oracle keeps outputing an invalid URL message. I've tried the following:

```
jdbc:oracle:oci10:@ldap://server:port/xyz,cn=abc,dc=def,dc=ghi

jdbc:oracle:oci10:@xyz
```

I've got my ORACLE_HOME set for a 10g database. I've added the libraries to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. I've set java.library.path system property. Finally, I can connect using sqlplus and the symbolic oid name.

What connect string should be used?

Answer (score 3):

This URL works for me,

```
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:oci:@<name_from_tnsnames.ora>", "user", "password");
```

If you are using OCI driver, you need a Oracle client installation from where you run this code. And you should have the valid working entry in the tnsnames.ora.

If you use incompatible ojdbc jar you would get java.library.path error. I used the ojdbc6.jar from the oracle client installation location `C:\app\client\jjayarman\product\12.1.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar`.

I use Oracle Database 12c / Java 1.7 on 64bit Windows7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know using the protocol `:oci10:` is incorrect, it should be `:oci:`. See also [this FAQ on Oracle JDBC](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)

Comment: You are correct about this. When I changed it to just oci, I don't get the invalid URL exception. However, I still can't connect to oid. It seems to time out. Using, though, a direct host:port:sid identifier, though, works

Comment: Not sure if it is helpful, but [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/instclnt.htm#CHDDGJDJ) mentions that it is necessary to have the `TNS_ADMIN` or `ORACLE_HOME` environment variables set when using tnsnames.ora entries.